# Scatter plot with shared datetime colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, colorbar

I want to plot a scatter plot based on longitude and latitude. Size of scatter plot depends on another value "LF".

```
longitude = df['evlo']
latitude = df['evla']
lf = df['LF']

# Define the size based on the LF values
size = lf
```

there is another column which has the dates information and i convert it into datetime format:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fold'].str[0:8], format='%Y%m%d')

df['dates'] = df['dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Output is in this format:

```
1       2020-04-20
2       2020-04-20
3       2020-04-20
4       2020-04-21
           ...    
1485    2020-06-12
1486    2020-06-12
1487    2020-06-12
1488    2020-06-12
1489    2020-06-12
```

I want to plot scatter subplot with 15 days interval with a shared colorbar. I have done this work but seems like every subplots has its own colorba, for example blue and red are present in each subplots which should not in real case. Below is my attempt:

```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# Filter data based on LF values

df_lf_more_than_1 = df[df['LF'] > 1]

# Get the minimum and maximum dates in the filtered data
min_date = df_lf_more_than_1['dates'].min()
max_date = df_lf_more_than_1['dates'].max()


# Create a figure with four subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 10),sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes = axes.flatten()    
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    # Calculate the start and end dates for the current interval
    start_date = min_date + pd.DateOffset(days=i * 15)
    end_date = start_date + pd.DateOffset(days=14)

    
    # Filter the data for the current interval
    df_interval = df_lf_more_than_1[(df_lf_more_than_1['dates'] >= start_date)
                                    & (df_lf_more_than_1['dates'] <= end_date)]
    # Plot the scatter plot for the current interval
    scatter = ax.scatter(df_interval['evlo'], df_interval['evla'], 
                         s=df_interval['LF']*5,
                         c=mdates.date2num(df_interval['dates']), cmap='jet')
        
 
    # Set the title of the subplot to the start and end dates
    ax.set_title(f'Interval: {start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} - {end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}')

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
        

cax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.7, 0.03])  # Position of the colorbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet'), cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.09)

plt.show()`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens because you do not specify the `vmin` and `vmax` when you scatter plot. If you do not specify the data range, the entire range of the colormap is used to cover the data. See the description [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). You can see this if you make individual colorbars for each plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize = (7, 3))
fig.suptitle("Not specifying vmin and vmax")

# plotting two plots with different time ranges
for ax, t1, t2 in zip([ax1, ax2], [0, 5], [5, 10]):
    longitude = np.random.uniform(10, 20, 50)
    latitude = np.random.uniform(50, 60, 50)
    t = np.linspace(t1, t2, 50)

    tmp = ax.scatter(x = longitude, y = latitude, c = t, cmap = "jet")
    plt.colorbar(tmp, ax = ax)

plt.show()
```

which yields this plot where the color range is the same for both but the values are different.

[image]

If you specify the same data range for all subplots, f.ex. your initial and final timestep, all points will be colored according to the same color range. In the example to full range is from 0 to 10.

```
tmp = ax.scatter(x = longitude, y = latitude, c = t, cmap = "jet", vmin = 0, vmax = 10)
```

This yields this plot:

[image]

The values on each colorbar are the same, and the points are colored by the same scale.

So to make the shared colorbar make sense, you need to make sure that the data range for the colormap is shared by all subplots and that this data range corresponds to the initial and final timestep in your data.